Using Sequelize to define a 1:m relationship between two models (+ creating migrations)
I am confused on the intended workflow with Sequelize. I have found some documentation that refers to a workflow that uses sequelize-cli, while others seem to create bespoke one-off javascript scripts that do the initialization. It seems the framework and tooling are largely flexible, but that flexibility results in a confusing and steep learning curve for beginners.
I want to create a simple 1:M model and have the db initialized with the corresponding schema. Simplified model concept:
Destination:
title:string
description:string

Views: (things to do at Destination)
title:string
description:string

Associations: Destinations have many Views, Views have one Destination.
Using the CLI we can do something like:
# Destinations
sequelize-cli --env $ENV \
   model:create \
        --name Destinations \
        --attributes \
            title:string,description:string

# Views
sequelize-cli --env $ENV \
   model:create \
        --name Views \
        --attributes \
            title:string,description:string

This results in a model and a migration being generated for both:
./models/destination.js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Destinations extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
    }
  }
  Destinations.init({
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Destinations',
  });
  return Destinations;
};

./models/views.js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Views extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
    }
  }
  Views.init({
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Views',
  });
  return Views;
};

And associated migrations:
./migrations/<number>-create-destinations.js
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Destinations', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Destinations');
  }
};

./migrations/<number>-create-views.js
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Views', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Views');
  }
};

And a small edit needs to be made to the model definitions to assign the associations:
In ./models/destination.js
    static associate(models) {
      Destinations.hasMany(models.Views)
    }

In ./models/views.js
    static associate(models) {
      Views.hasOne(models.Destinations)
      Views.belongsTo(models.Destinations)
    }

And then you can use the CLI to create the db following your newly defined schema:
sequelize-cli --env development db:create
sequelize-cli --env development db:migrate

So this objectively seems like it would work, and seems to be the intended workflow from what I gather. And it sort of does work - except the associations are not accounted for in the created db schema. Presumably because the foreign keys and such are not defined in the migrations that the CLI generates. Further presumably because they are not defined in the --attributes field of the CLI invocation.
So it seems like I need to manually add the associate() function definition within each model definition and also patch the migration file after defining the associations? So then associate() method is strictly for runtime and does not help define model schema relationships?
Am I missing something from my applied workflow? Am I using it incorrectly?

Yes, associate is only for defining runtime links between models so that you can make queries with associated models. And yes, you need to change migrations and add FKs. Also please remove hasOne association. For 1:N relationship you should define only hasMany+belongsTo counterpart associations.

@Anatoly this is fine, but it's somewhat unclear from the documentation what level of manual configuration is required. So if this is the intent then so be it. Regarding your comment - why would you not specify that (in this case) a View.hasOne(Destination)? I should have a destination_id (or some such) column in each View to reference the destination that it is associated with, no? Perhaps I misunderstand the intent of belongsTo.

hasOne is a counterpart of belongsTo in 1:1 relationship and not in 1:N (1:N should be described with hasMany/belongsTo). You call belongsTo on a model that has a FK column and call hasOne on  a model to which the latter FK was indicated in belongsTo.

@Anatoly must you specify the FK with some special attributes for this to work? I edited the associations as you suggested. I also added the FK in the Views.init call as destinationId:DataTypes.INTEGER. and then adjusted the associate call as Views.belongsTo(models.Destinations, { foreignKey: 'destinationId' }). However, the queries always fail with column Views.DestinationId does not exist and I can't track down where this is coming from. I thought the belongsTo options would be sufficient to rename the FK within the runtime models, but it appears to have no effect.

You should indicate the same foreignKey: 'destinationId' for both counterpart associations

@Anatoly while that did solve the problem, it seems like a poor requirement. Why should the (in this case) Destination model care what the FK is named in the Views model?

Because you can really have different keys to have different relationships between the same models. By default Sequelize assumes the FK name as Model+Id
